# Jquery Cycle with Video

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an automated slideshow on my website with multiple images, videos (some embedded from YouTube), and other similar media using jQuery Cycle.  Since Cycle has various transitions I prefer this rather than Cycle 2.  I was able to create slideshow that pulls up all images and videos, but the video on the page starts automatically even before it gets displayed. I need the video to play when it is displaying/focused instead of when the page loads. How can I start playing the video when it is focused/displayed on jQuery Cycle?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'all', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...      
                timeoutFn: calculateTimeout,
                //before: onBefore,
                //after: onAfter,
            });
        });

        var timeouts = [];
        function calculateTimeout(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
            var index = opts.currSlide; 
            return timeouts[index] * 1000; 
        }; 

    function addTimeout(timeoutInSec){
        timeouts.push(timeoutInSec);
    };
    </script>

    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${list}">
    <div class="slideshow" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <c:if test="${listValue.getType().getName() eq 'IMAGE'}">
          <img src="${imagefile}"/>
          <script>addTimeout("${listValue.getTimeout()}")</script>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${listValue.getType().getName() eq 'VIDEO'}">
          <video id="video" controls autoplay loop style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <source src="abc.mp4">
         </video> 
         <script>addTimeout("${listValue.getTimeout()}")</script>
         </c:if>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This may help you [HTML Audio/Video DOM pause() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp) you could pause all your videos and play them when visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the video wia javascript/jQuery using such a function :

```
var video = $('#video').get(0);
video.play();
```

So basically, you need to remove the `autoplay` attribute from the video tag, and use the piece of code above when the video is made visible (see the `onAfter` section).

Notice that you can use (or not) the `video.load()` function. Right now, you are preloading every video in your slideshow, this can cause performance issue.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I tried as you suggested var video = $('#video').get(0);video.play(); but it plays only the first video, how can I automatically play every video in the loop when it gets displayed in the cycle?.  Thanks.

Comment: Its working now by adding this,  function onBefore(curr, next, opts){

 if (next.nodeName == "VIDEO"){
  var vid = document.getElementById(next.id);
  vid.play();

 } }  Thank you very much guys.